# Cabal couldnt figure out LLVM verison.

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am trying to install the repa-v4l2 package and I get an error I dont know how to fix:

```
kyle@Kyles-Comp:~$ sudo cabal install repa-v4l2
[sudo] password for kyle: 
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring repa-v4l2-0.2.0.0...
Building repa-v4l2-0.2.0.0...
Preprocessing library repa-v4l2-0.2.0.0...
[1 of 2] Compiling Graphics.Webcam.Linux.Internal( src/Graphics/Webcam/Linux/Internal.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Webcam/Linux/Internal.o )

<no location info>:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
    Make sure you have installed LLVM
ghc: could not execute: opt
Failed to install repa-v4l2-0.2.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
repa-v4l2-0.2.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How do you help LLVM figure out the verison?

Comment: Do you have LLVM's executables (opt and friends) in your PATH? If so, what are they called? Perhaps they are named opt-(version) etc.

Comment: @gspr how do i find that out?

Comment: By inspecting the files that came with your installation of LLVM. If you used a package manager (which you should if you're not sure about what you're doing), some likely candidates are /usr/bin/llvm-* and friends.

Comment: @gspr I dont have any type of folder named like LLVM how do I download it?

Comment: @KyleMcKean You can install LLVM from your package manager. See the documentation for your distribution for more information.